LazyColumn off scroll and overscroll effect when all items fit in the screen
ran into the fact that lazycolumn disables the overscroll effect if all elements successfully fit in the screen.
The same RecyclerView always draws the overscroll effect no matter how many items it has displayed
Gif when items don't fit in the screen
https://jmp.sh/s/8au70jqyBApCOz8dovYQ
Gif when items fit in the screen
https://jmp.sh/s/V0EXX4xUtSoBRu5a7OGg

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
